# Python : I want to reverse a string by converting it to list

Tags: python

I want to reverse a string by converting it to a list.

I am getting a null output.

```
>>> print(list([i for i in s3]).reverse())
None
>>> print(list([i for i in s3]))
['g', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'd']
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You can just reverse a string with `str[::-1]`.

Comment: where is the null output? Your print is showing a list, no?

Comment: @hansaplast - Line 2 of the code block.

Comment: @dabadaba `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` ;)

Comment: lol true, let's just go with `s`